# How do I store 3D models on the server in my ARKit project?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, swift5

There are too many 3D models in the iOS app and the size of the app is too high. I want to keep 3D models on the Internet (Parse Server). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do that, you can for example create your own web server to serve your files or use existing solutions such as Amazon S3 (there is a lot of others solutions !).

Upload all your files to your Amazon S3 bucket and then create a utility in Swift to download your assets when needed.
You will find an example of how to download your file in Swift in this page using the [AWS SDK](https://github.com/swift-aws/aws-sdk-swift)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Which file will I add to the database? (.scn) I want to keep the files on the Back4App platform.

Comment: I didn't see that you were using this solution. I have no experience with this platform but as I can see you can store file on it. Yes you can put your scn files on your storage. Hard to answer, as I don't know exactly your projects structure.

Comment: Do I need to download the models? Can I run it through url?

Comment: I think you need to download models. There is probably a way to do this without downloading, but don't spend time on that. Make your app small as possible to be published on appStore. And then download models when you want to use them. And if you have a lot of models, you can maybe allow user to clean downloaded files to avoid uninstall app when missing space on phone.